# "intermediate directory contains no translation units" error while Coverity Static Analysis of my Java project

Tags: java, static-analysis, coverity

Recieved following warning while capturing the build for my project on Coverity.
[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cov-build` needs to know about what compilers you have in your build system. This is informed by the generated configs (using `cov-configure`).

For a Java project, usually `cov-configure --java` is sufficient. This will have `cov-build` look for `javac` invocations.

Another common problem is that you didn't do a clean build, so no actual compilations were seen.

If you've configured Java properly and captured a clean build and still aren't seeing TUs emitted, then you'll need to inspect the build log (underneath `<intermediate directory>/build-log.txt`). This should give some indication of what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experiences in Coverity.
I got similar error with you, and i added sub command "--record-only" or "--ro", then error is solved.

Comment: I use separate record and replay stages, but have just seen this error during the analyze stage.

This was a Jenkins build triggered manually.  So no files in the repo had changed, and Jenkins was reusing a workspace which already had an up-to-date build.

I would have expected analyze to treat this as a no-op, as its not a rare case.  The purpose of retaining the intermediate directory is enable incremental analysis.  In this case the increment was zero.

Comment: (Actually may not be Coverity issue - there is a step which deletes the intermediate dir if it was produced by an old version.  This may be the cause - in which case it should be a full clean of the workspace instead).